# I am trying to convert Java AES encryption to NodeJs. This is what I have tried so far

Tags: java, node.js, encryption, cryptography, aes

Java encryption code.

```
import java.security.spec.KeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.SecretKeyFactory;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.PBEKeySpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.jarvis.accountopeningv2.model.PartChanRequestDTO;
import com.jarvis.accountopeningv2.model.TemplateDTO;

public class SecurityService {

    private static final String ALGORITHM = "AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING";
    
    
    public static String encryptpayload(String value, String key) {
        String encryptedData = null;
        try {
            
            
            IvParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec(key.substring(0, 16).getBytes("UTF-8"));
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.substring(0, 32).getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec, iv);

            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            encryptedData = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(encrypted);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            encryptedData = null;
        }
        return encryptedData;
    }
    
}
```

This is what I have tried.

```
function SecurityFunc(request) {

        const digest = 'SHA256';
            var secretkey = 'fgbnhgfcjhgfcvjkhgfcvjkhgfcvbjbnvcjhnbvcfghjnbvc';     // 256 character
            var iv = Buffer.from(secretkey.substring(0,16), 'utf-8', 'aes');
            const key = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(secretkey, 'boooooo!!', 65536, 32, digest);
            const cipher = crypto.createCipheriv('aes-256-cbc', key, iv);
            let encrypted = cipher.update(`${request}`, 'ascii', 'base64');
            encrypted += cipher.final('base64');
            return encrypted;

}
```

I have searched a lot about this. I got these questions on stack overflow

Difference in key lengths between crypto.pbkdf2 (node.js) and PBEKeySpec, AES/CBC/PKCS5PADDING IV - Decryption in NodeJs (Encrypted in Java) I have tried both of them but none of them resolved my query.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Where is your PBE in Java? I don't see PBKDF2 mentioned at all. Please create an [mcve]. When you are pointing out other Q/As then please create *links* to the questions.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to make the 2 compatible or just port the code from Java to JavaScript?

Update: apparently PKCS#5 will work the same as for PKCS#7 so that isn't your issue.

The key length should be 32-bytes in both cases.

If you don't need backwards compatibility, I'd recommend using AES in GCM mode rather than CBC as it includes tamper protection.

Comment: What Java crypto calls `PKCS5PADDING` _is_ the extended-to-include-block16 form, and since 2017 PKCS5 itself actually does the same, see RFC8018 Appendix B.2.4-5.

Comment: Ah nice one. I didn't know that!